# MAUI Application doesn't update UI even after restart

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

The MAUI Application is built using Visual Studio Community 2022.

When editing any XAML file and then starting the application, the changes are not loaded in the application. In order to see the changes I have to rebuild the whole project. The Hot Reload functionality is not working either.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its likely something corrupted in temporary project files, or associated with the project on the target device.

- Delete solution's hidden `.vs` folder, and all .bin and .obj folders in your solution.
- If targetting mobile: On device or emulator's home screen, Remove (or Uninstall) App. This deletes any debug info stored with it.

More extreme actions if needed:

- If targetting an actual mobile device: power it off (so it shuts down; not just a blank screen). Then back on.
- If targetting mobile: "Soft Reset". Details depend on device or emulator. Preserves apps and data; clears some internal system settings.
- If targetting mobile: "Factory Reset". Clears all data.

---

- If only this one project is bad: copy (or download from source repo) ONLY the project sources, to a new folder. Result should be similar to the first suggestion to delete .vs/.bin/.obj.
  Just making sure there isn't something somehow going wrong in the current project location.

---

- If you suspect Visual Studio itself is corrupt:
- - Delete ALL versions of Visual Studio. (Keep any old one you need. Or consider re-installing it later.)
- - Reboot PC.
- - Download and install current Visual Studio.

Comment: After some struggling I found that clicking Deploy before running fixes the problem, so it seems that Deploy is not automatically triggered.

Comment: Though, I do not know why Deploy is not automatically triggered.